# Meaning and origin of phrase "wear heart on sleeve"

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrases

What does the phrase "wear (one's) heart on (one's) sleeve" mean?

I would appreciate if you could also tell me the origin of the same.

Comment: First Google result tells you both: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wear_one's_heart_on_one's_sleeve

Comment: To be fair to the OP, the Wiktionary entry you cite lists the earliest recorded use of the phrase in Shakespeare's *Othello*, but that does not *necessarily* mean that the passage cited is the origin of the phrase. Shakespeare could have picked it up from daily speech or written sources no longer available to us. Which is just to say, the *Othello* passage should be called the earliest recorded use of the phrase, not necessarily the origin of the phrase.

Comment: @Michael Broder: Are you accusing the Bard of plagiarism?

Comment: @MichaelBroder You are certainly right, and it always good to exercise healthy caution when using WikiAnything. In this case, however, I believe Wiktionary has it right.

Comment: Thank you choster, I did look at the link, however I felt there was more to it and was hoping for some better insights, hence I posted the question here.Thanks

Comment: @PreetieSekhon You deserve better insight than you received. As I noted above, you asked for the *origin* of the phrase, and we gave you the *first recorded appearance* of the phrase, which may or may not be the same thing. It may be the best we can do, but we should at least be able to explain the distinction to you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I assume you are just kidding. But this is a difficult issue for students and non-specialists. So I will address your question as an earnest one. No, I am not accusing Shakespeare of plagiarism. He's not using somebody else's words as his own without attribution. He's a poet and playwright. He makes poems and plays out of the narrative and verbal material around him. "Wearing your heart on your sleeve" may in fact have been a current expression in the spoken English of Shakespeare's time, and his use of it in Othello may be just the earliest recorded example we possess.

Comment: @Michael Broder: Kidding? This is a serious topic! Money is involved. Why, Plagiarism has enjoyed a huge increase in tourism since the Bard's house on its main street was opened to the public.

Comment: Someone who wears his heart on his sleeve obviously can't play his cards close to his chest.

Answer (score 1):

It means simply to be transparent emotionally.  When you wear your heart on your sleeve, people can see quite readily what emotions you are feeling because you emote them.  In other words, they're as obvious as the sleeves on your shirt (or sweater, or coat, or tunic, or jacket, or whatever).

As for the origin of the phrase, I'll leave that to a colleague who is more astute than I.

Answer (score 0):

When you wear your heart on your sleeves, you don't disguise your emotion, instead you let them expose out in your appearance.

For instance, when you feel happy, the happiness will be indicated all over your face.